# sequence of page references by a program

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, valgrind

How can I have the sequence of pages referenced by a program using Valgrid or any other tool? I don't want the total count of hits or misses but the exact list of page numbers ordered by access. I want to use this sequence as the input of a simulated memory management algorithm.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware how to do it on other operating systems, but on linux you can get PFNs from /proc/*PID*/pagemap:

> The /proc/pid/pagemap gives the PFN, which can be used to find the pageflags
>   using /proc/kpageflags and number of times a page is mapped using
>   /proc/kpagecount. For detailed explanation, see Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt.